# Can I tell git to ignore Linux permissions?

Tags: linux, git

I am developing on Windows and uploading to a Linux cloud server using git, via Bitbucket.

I edited a shell script, which on Windows has permissions

```
-rwxr-xr-x
```

For some reason, when it gets to Linux, it has permissions

```
-rw-r--r--
```

To make it executable I do:

```
chmod +x <my_script>.sh
```

Later, I edit the script back on Windows and push the changes up to Bitbucket. When I try to

```
git pull
```

back on the cloud I get the following error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        <path>/<my_script>.sh
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
```

All I did on the cloud was make the file executable. I didn't edit it! Can I tell git to get on with the merge and ignore file permissions? If not, how best to deal with this situation?

I realize I could unset the permissions

```
chmod -x <my_script>.sh
```

do the pull, and then reset the permissions

```
chmod +x <my_script>.sh
```

But to have to do this each time I edit is a pain. Is there a better way?

Comment: Try `sh myscript.sh` instead

Comment: @davidbaumann I hear you. This way I don't need to change the permissions. But...I'd still like to know if I can tell git to ignore the permissions. After all, the text has not been touched. And sometimes I just get an itchy trigger finger and want to make my shell scripts executable :->.

Comment: Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes

Comment: @davidbaumann Thanks for the link. It seems to be what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure git to ignore the executable bit:

```
git config --global core.fileMode false
```

See more details here:

[man git-config](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html)

Actually found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes).